# Would file locking here prevent file corruption?

Tags: php, file

Would the flock() function prevent file corruption in this case whilst writing the file (in case two processes happen to try and write data to the file at the same time)?

```php
    // Read the file data
    $file_data = "Stuff you want to add\n";
    $file_data .= file_get_contents('foo.txt');

    // Open the file for writing and get an exclusive lock
    $fp = fopen('foo.txt', 'w');
    flock($fp, LOCK_EX);

    // Write the new data at the start of the file
    file_put_contents('foo.txt', $file_data);

    // Close and unlock the file
    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: [`file_put_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) has it's own option for `LOCK_EX`

Comment: Doh! Cheers....

Comment: Just tried this. `flock`  locks the file, so you can't write to it with  `file_put_contents`: _Warning: file_put_contents(): Only 0 of 22 bytes written_

Comment: You create `$fp` but then ignore it when writing. Are you trying to open two handles on the same file from the same process in order to test something or it's just a bug?